# Trouble with evaluating pre-trained model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a fine-tuned version of the inceptionV3 model that I want to test on a new dataset. However, I am getting error `No model found in config file.`

This is my code,

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('/home/saved_model/CNN_inceptionv3.h5')

CLASS_1_data = '/home/spectrograms/data/c1'

def label_img(img):
    word_label = img[:5]
    if img[1] == '1':
      return [1,0]
    elif img[1] == '3':
      return [0,1]

def create_data(data,loc): #loads data into a list
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(loc)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(loc,img)
        img = Image.open(path) 
        img = ImageOps.grayscale(img) 
        # w,h = img.size
        # img = img.resize((w//3,h//3))
        data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    return data

def make_X_and_Y(set): #split data into numpy arrays of inputs and outputs
  set_X,set_Y = [],[]
  n = len(set)
  for i in range(n):
    set_X.append(set[i][0])
    set_Y.append(set[i][1])
  return np.array(set_X),np.array(set_Y)

data = []
data = create_data(data,CLASS_1_data)
data = np.array(data)

X_data,Y_data = make_X_and_Y(data)

X_data = X_data.astype('float32')

X_data /= 255 

results = model.evaluate(X-data, Y_data, batch_size=5)
```

What is the error here? How can I correct it and test my model?

Comment: have you saved the weights only or the model only? model.save or model.save_weights?

Comment: I used model.save_weights

Answer (score 0):

to load the model you have to use `model.save` in case you want to load onlyy the wieghts `model.save_weights`.
In your case use `model.save` and it will upload the model.
Let me know.
Or you can load the model from json.

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

You have the weights so... load json and create model

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

load weights into new model

```
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

let me know!

Comment: I used the model.save_weights after training. So that means I only saved the weights right? From what I understand, I have two options now, 1 - build the models back and load the saved weights and use them on my data, 2 -  train the model again save it using model.save(). Am I right?

Comment: Or load the model not from h5 file but from json.Check the edit of my answer!

Comment: Accidentally I lost the architecture of my model. So the only way now is to make the model again and train and save model and weights right?

Comment: or build the model from scratch and load the weights or as you said is right

Comment: have you news??